# selecting non matching records from full outer join

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables

```
tb1 
-------
1,ali
2,ana
3,kim
6,git
8,sen
9,pam

tb2
-------
2,joy
3,fin
4,roy
5,dina
9,tim

output
-------
1,ali
2,joy
3,fin
4,roy
5,dina
6,git
8,sen
9,tim
```

I need to join two tables and for common columns I should consider id and name from tb2 else it is from tb1.
along with this I need non matching records from both the tables
my query:

```
select case when tb1.id=tb2.id then tb2.id else tb1.id end as id , case when tb1.id=tb2.id then tb2.name else tb1.name end as name  
  from tb1 full outer join tb2
  on tb1.id=tb2.id;
```

its not giving me the non-matching records.
how can I achieve this without adding multiple checks for null?

Comment: I assume you're using SQL Server since you are using `FULL OUTER JOIN`, correct? Instead of using `JOIN` have you played with `UNION` any to union both results and then perhaps select from it as a subquery instead? Just a quick idea without testing but I post all my SQL query question on https://stackoverflow.com and not here. Also consider putting some data on http://sqlfiddle.com if you get a chance and post a link on your question to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage for `full outer join` looks correct, but the select terms won't handle missing items correctly. Using `coalesce` should do the trick:

```
SELECT          COALESCE (tb2.id, tb1.id) AS id, COALESCE (tb2.name, tb1.name) AS name
FROM            tb1
FULL OUTER JOIN tb2 ON tb1.id = tb2.id;
```

Comment: yeah what will happen if ids are matching but tb2.name is null and tb1.name has some value? will it still consider tb1.name ?

Comment: @user yup, that's what the `coalesce` call is there for.

Comment: hmm but i want to pick up records from tb2 for all columns if id is matching between two so i used row_number that worked